# Using the JQuery UI datepicker instead the bootstrap 3 datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am running side by side a site made with bootstrap 3 and JQuery UI. I prefer to run the JQuery UI datepicker, but I don't know how to disable the bootstrap one, that is the one that gets executed when I run the $("#DueDate").datepicker({... code.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you including JQuery UI before Bootstrap? If so, try adding it afterwards and it should run instead of Bootstrap's datepicker.

Comment: Bootstrap does not come with a datepicker -- you need to specifically include the plug-in. So it's just a matter of removing the plug-in script.

Comment: Yeah, Bootstrap itself doesn't come with a datepicker. There are some third-party ones for it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order in which the scripts load.

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```